# Typedef struct not working

Tags: esp8266, struct, typedef

I made this simple code but I'm getting the following error

```
exit status 1
'RGB' does not name a type
```

```
typedef struct
RGB
{
        double r;
        double g;
        double b;
};

RGB led;

RGB func(){
  RGB temp;
  return RGB;
}
```

I am not getting the error on "RGB led" but just on the function.
Does anyone know a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: The typedef syntax is "typedef [known type] [new name];" so RGB would go after the closing brace of the structure definition. Or see @edgarbonet's post for another alternative.

Answer (score 4):

In plain C, structs are identified by "struc tags", which do not live in
the same namespace as type names. Thus, if you declare

```cpp
struct RGB {
    ...
};
```

a variable of this type should be declared as

```cpp
struct RGB led;
```

In order to avoid the inconvenience of repeatedly typing `struct`, a
common idiom is to define it as a type:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    ...
} RGB;

RGB led;
```

The Arduino environment, however, is based on the C++ programming
language. In C++ struct tags *are* types, and you thus do not need the
typedef:

```cpp
struct RGB {
    ...
};

RGB led;
```

This is the recommended idiom in C++: just remove the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors:

you are returning a class type, and not the *temp* object

```
  RGB func(){
    RGB temp;
    return RGB; --> return temp;
  }
```

To use your typedef you should put the struct "name" after the braced parenthesis:

```
typedef struct
{
    double r;
    double g;
    double b;
} RGB;
```

Comment: This works, thanks!